# Вывод select через button

Tags: javascript

При нажатии кнопки должна появится та часть массива которая указана в select.

```js
let selStation = document.querySelector('#select-station');
let btnStation = document.querySelector('.btn-station');

const metro = {
 "red" : [
   'Академгородок', 'Житомирская', 'Святошин', 'Нивки',
   ],
 "blue" : [
   'ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»', 'Героев Днепра', 'Оболонь', 'Почайна',
 ],
 "green" : [
   'Сырец', 'Дорогожичи', 'Герцена', 'Лукьяновская',
 ]
}

let massKey = Object.keys(metro);
for( let i = 0; i < massKey.length; i++) {
  selStation.add(new Option(massKey[i]))
}

btnStation.addEventListener('click', function () {
 let val = metro[this.value];
 for( let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
  document.write(val[i]);
 }
})
```

```html
<select id="select-station"></select>
<button class="btn-station">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let selStation = document.querySelector('#select-station');
let btnStation = document.querySelector('.btn-station');

const metro = {
  "red": ['Академгородок', 'Житомирская', 'Святошин', 'Нивки'],
  "blue": ['ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»', 'Героев Днепра', 'Оболонь', 'Почайна'],
  "green": ['Сырец', 'Дорогожичи', 'Герцена', 'Лукьяновская']
};

Object.keys(metro).forEach(i => selStation.add(new Option(i)));

btnStation.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let val = metro[selStation.value];
  output.innerHTML = val.join('<br/>');
});
```

```html
<select id="select-station"></select>
<button class="btn-station">Send</button>
<div id='output'></div>
```